# Order the Union query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

> 1- Cars (Columns :ID,Name,Description,Image)
>
> 2- Motorcycles (Columns :ID,Name,Description,Image)

I want to loop two tables on the vehicles.php page. I want to sort by ID in the loop.

I Codes

**CARS**

```
$cars= $baglan->query("SELECT * FROM Cars ORDER BY id", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      
if ( $cars->rowCount() )
foreach( $cars as $car){ 
-
}}
```

**MOTORCYCLES**

```
$query= $baglan->query("SELECT * FROM Motorcycles ORDER BY id", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      
if ( $query->rowCount() )
foreach( $query as $row){ 
-
}}
```

**How do I combine these two queries?**

This code does not work

```
   $vehicles= $baglan->query("SELECT * FROM Motorcycles , Cars ORDER BY id", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     
    if ( $vehicles->rowCount() )
    foreach( $vehicles as $vehicle){ 
    -
    }}
```

Thank you

Comment: They look like the same query?

Comment: you can probably merge em both and just add what kind of vehicle to distinguish if its a car or motorcycle

Comment: yes, both of the same query

Comment: Do you want to mix cars and motorcycles, or display all the cars then all the motorcycles?

Comment: Mixing cars and motorcycles

Comment: If the `UNION` queries don't work, I presume the tables have different columns? So, can you give us the table structures please.

Comment: Tables with the same structure

Comment: if tables have the same structure then **obviously** it should be just one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to merge them in one query, you can use `UNION` in mysql, but I highly recommend you to use it only if columns of two tables are the same.

```
try {
    $vehicles = $baglan->query("
        SET @id:=0;
        SELECT (@id:=@id+1) AS `ID`,`Name`,`Description`,`Image` FROM (
            (SELECT * FROM `Cars` ORDER BY `ID`)
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM `Motorcycles` ORDER BY `ID`)
        ) AS `Vehicles`;
    ", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($vehicles->rowCount()) {
        $id = 1;
        foreach($vehicles as $vehicle) { 
            echo $id++; // Use $id because the `id` column is from two tables
            // use other fields normally
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But if you want to order the mixed data on the original ID column, you can use this (descending for example):

```
try {
    $vehicles = $baglan->query("
        SELECT * FROM (
            (SELECT * FROM `Cars` ORDER BY `ID` DESC)
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM `Motorcycles` ORDER BY `ID` DESC)
        ) AS `Vehicles`
        ORDER BY `ID` DESC;
    ", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($vehicles->rowCount()) {
        $id = 1;
        foreach($vehicles as $vehicle) { 
            echo $id++; // Use $id because the `id` column is from two tables
            // use other fields normally
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean in

Comment: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean in

Line: if ($vehicles->rowCount()) {

Comment: @MLF OP seems to be using PDO, not MySQLi. The `$conn->error` property is MySQLi only, PDO uses different methods of getting the returned errors.

Comment: @Qirel The answer is edited based on PDO style of coding. check again.

Comment: Work code:
SELECT * FROM cars UNION SELECT * FROM motorcyles ORDER BY id DESC

But but sort errors.

Comment: You are confusing everyone. What's the name of your tables? `gercekdugunler` or `Cars` or `Vehicles`?!!

Comment: The newly edited post adds a new `id` column to make sorting avaiable without duplicate IDs.

Comment: As tar as I can tell, the OP wants to sort their records not enumerate them

Comment: Please be careful on Linux or any other OS filesystem behavior: they are case-sensitive. Since tables are stored as files with the same name to the table name, then if you name your table as `Cars` for example and use `cars` (with lower 'c') then you will have "Table `cars` not found" error or something like this because the file is named as `Cars` not `cars`.

Comment: @YourCommonSense So use this query:

SELECT * FROM ((SELECT * FROM Cars ORDER BY ID) UNION (SELECT * FROM Motorcycles ORDER BY ID)) AS Vehicles ORDER BY ID;

Comment: Add `desc` at the end of query and remember: you should tell us exactly what you want in your question. We don't have mind-reading abilities.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM ((SELECT * FROM motorcyles ORDER BY id DESC) UNION (SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY id DESC)) AS vehicles ORDER BY id DESC;

But the ID is incorrectly sorted. 

Example

73,72,70,67,68,69

Comment: I used exactly the query used in my answer and the result is correctly sorted: `73,72,70,69,68,67`

Comment: Use second part of my answer.

Comment: My problem is solved. How much thank you. Gratefulness

Comment: BTW, it's better to mix your two tables in one called `Vehicles` and separate cars and motorcycles with a column called `type_id` that is a foreign key to a new table called `Types` containing different types of vehicles with different IDs. You should use database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Since they have the same columns, you can use a `UNION`,

```sql
SELECT * FROM Motorcycles
UNION
SELECT * FROM Cars
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` doesn't work for `SELECT` in a `UNION`: "Use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows
appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows"

Comment: Once again, Nick - you're absolutely correct! I merely copied the OP's queries, I'll edit the `ORDER BY`s out ;-) Cheers!

Comment: How does it not work? Which error-message does it produce? If you're using PDO, enable PDO to throw exceptions and see which error it returned. Or do `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` where `$dbh` is your connection object.

Comment: Work code: SELECT * FROM cars UNION SELECT * FROM motorcyles ORDER BY id DESC But but sort errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT * FROM Motorcycles
UNION
SELECT * FROM Cars)
ORDER BY ID
```